# How to take a screenshot using MediaProjection API?

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I am new to MediaProjection API and I have very limited knowledge in computer graphics. I need help with as in how to use this particular API. What should I study to learn to use this API. Google documentation gives little information. And everywhere I look in the internet, everyone is making a screen recorder with it but no one has posted a code sample for taking screenshots using this API.

Comment: I have a chapter on the media projection APIs in [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/). It includes samples for screenshots and screencasts.

Comment: Ok I will go through your book.. thanks :)

Comment: I went through your book.. now its working.. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the book as mentioned by @Commonsware in the comment and it actually helped me